# Filter pandas dataframe to keep outliers only for every column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe :

| year | var1 | var2 | var3 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1970 | 14.52 | 2.88 | 20510 | … |
| 1970 | 12.36 | 5.5 | 22320 | … |
| 1970 | 11.85 | 3.12 | 21640 | … |
| 1970 | 18.30 | 6.3 | 25200 | … |

For each and every column (`vari`), I would like to keep outliers only (like with `df[vari].quantile(0.99)`). Every column has different meaning so the boundary condition is column dependant.

I found many similar questions but most of them deal with either a single column to filter, an common outlier boundary across all columns, or results in a dataframe with values that respect the condition for every column whereas I need them for any column.

**I need to plot every column separately so I have to keep rows that have at least an outlier in one of the columns.**

My idea is to replace non-outlier values in each column by NaN but I can't find a simple way to filter my data.

Expected output is like :

| year | var1 | var2 | var3 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1970 | 14.52 | NaN | NaN | … |
| 1970 | NaN | 5.5 | 24500 | … |
| 1970 | NaN | Nan | NaN | … |
| 1970 | 18.30 | 6.3 | 25200 | … |

I tried something using `.apply` and `lambda` with no success :

```py
outliers = df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std() > 3).any(axis=1)]
```

This seems to return rows that have an outlier in *every* column.

I also tried something less elegant by looping on columns but the execution fails (probably due to erroneous logic… code below for the record) :

```py
for col in df.columns:
    filtered_col = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.NaN if (x <= df[col].quantile(0.99) and x >= df[col].quantile(0.01)) else x )
    df[col] = filtered_col
```

Do you have any idea on how I can tackle this issue ?

Comment: So for each row, if there is any outliers in any of the columns you want to keep that row and the outlier values in those columns with NaN for all other non outlier values in that row. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine, except that it mask the `year` column as well. So maybe your problem is just choosing the correct columns:

```
var_cols = df.columns[1:]

for col in var_cols:
    mm, MM = df[col].quantile([.01,.99])
    df[col] =df[col].where(df[col].between(mm,MM))
```

Output:

```
   year   var1  var2     var3
0  1970  14.52   NaN      NaN
1  1970  12.36  5.50  22320.0
2  1970    NaN  3.12  21640.0
3  1970    NaN   NaN      NaN
```

You can aslo do without the `for` loop:

```
mm = df[var_cols].quantile(.01)
MM = df[var_cols].quantile(.99)

df[var_cols] = df[var_cols].where(df[var_cols].le(MM) & df[var_cols].ge(mm))
```

For `mean` and `std`:

```
mean, std = df[var_cols].mean(), df[var_cols].std()
mm, MM = mean - 3*std, mean + 3*std
df[var_cols] = df[var_cols].where(df[var_cols].le(MM) & df[var_cols].ge(mm))
```

Comment: Great, thank you for pointing this out. I like the solution using `where()`. By the way, I think the condition is `df[var_cols] = df[var_cols].where(df[var_cols].ge(MM) | df[var_cols].le(mm))` to get the outliers only. Your solution is removing outliers instead. Same for the use of `between()` : I would like to get the outliers so values outside the range of `(mm, MM)`.

Comment: Also, could your solution be improved to remove rows with only NaN values ? I would like to keep rows with at least one outlier value in any of the columns. I can do that with an additional line of code, but I wonder if there is a way to filter those lines directly ?